# Image and CSS links broken after URL redirection

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-web-api

This is my directory structure of a webapi asp .net project:

```
Root

 Controllers

 View

   -JS

   -CSS

   -Images

   -A.html
```

My A.html contains links to css, images as this -
 `<img src="Images\a.png" />` OR `<link herf="Css/a.css"/>`

I use URL redirection so paths like "localhost/client" actually open A.html. But all my links are broken. What is the ideal way to solve this? First of all why is it broken. Does this mean that CSS/a.css now points to localhost/client/css/a.css which is not found? I do not want to hardcode the links path relative to the new path as that would mean the links will be broken when I open the html normally from the browser? Can I use some kind of variable in css and image paths to make it configurable?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ~.

Ex.

```
<img src="~/Images/a.png" /> 
<link herf="~/Css/a.css"/>
```

Comment: This does not work. This will work - src = "/View/Images/a.png" ( Note that I replaced ~ with / as I am in pure html). But if i just want to run the html file outside this folder it would break rather -  /Images/a.png will work. Hence I need dynamic name for src...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using WebApi (as your tag suggests) you can try [UrlHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.routing.urlhelper%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

```
Url.Content("~/Images/SomeImg.png")
```

will automatically resolve to the correct path to your resource.

Answer (score 0):

Use full paths. For example:

```
 D:\project\images\a.png
```